# How to determine SQL Server Instance name remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I know a that SQL Express is installed on a given computer. I have the SA password to that database. However I do not know the Instance Name.

(So the connection string would be "`Data Source=[IP Address]\????;User Id=sa;Password=[password]`")

Without logging into the box, how can I determine what the instance name?

Comment: `Without logging into the box...`  does that mean you don't have permission?  Or are you just looking for a creative solution?

Comment: If I have 100 instances then I would not want to log into the box. Or if I wanted to know what was exposed on the network, or perhaps the user does not have remote desktoping enabled. Other reasons are possible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the SQL Server tools installed locally,

```
osql -L
```

will output a list of all available SQL Servers (including their instance names) in your current network.

Comment: Works, *except*, A) does not work for "hidden" instances that are not broadcasting their names, B) nor for any instances that happen to be not started when this is run, and C) on larger networks, it typically does not find them all, even taking (A) and (B) into account (I don't know exactly why, I've always assumed it was some network thing).  AFAIK, the only 100% reliable method is querying the Services list for every system in the network.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. However iIt didn't work for me. I do see many (1000+) sql severs and instances however the one I am looking for is not on that list. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: @JohnSmith The reasons for this are explained in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! From another subnet I was able to get a different list.